# Setting file permissions in Ruby with File.open

Tags: ruby, linux, file, file-permissions

I wrote this to survey the permissions of files created with varying `perm` values

```
[0644, 0664, 0755, 0775].each do |perm|
  filename = "file#{perm}"
  File.open(filename, 'wb', perm) { |f| f.puts 'test' }
  puts '%o' % File::Stat.new(filename).mode
end
```

When run this will output:

```
100644
100644
100755
100755
```

Which is not what I expected. Why is the group write permission on the 2nd and 4th file not set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-new, Ruby simply uses the `open(2)` system call.  That respects the umask settings (removing any bits that are set in umask before actually setting permission bits).

Thus, you can achieve group writability by setting your umask to clear the group writable bit.  E.g. set it to `0002`.  More details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).